# Return percent-population of number of duplicate members

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This query works, and returns a percentage for which a field (or other row) condition is met:

```
SELECT
CONVERT(Decimal(5,2), CONVERT(Decimal(5,4), CONVERT(Float, (
--Conditional numerator query for percent-population, has to be converted to Float prior to division operation
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [MyTable] WHERE RTRIM(UPPER([FName])) = 'JOHN'
))/(
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [MyTable] --Numerator doesn't need to be converted
))*100)
```

This query also works, and returns a count of total number of members in a duplicate group:

```
WITH MySubquery AS (
SELECT COUNT([SupposedlyUnique]) AS Counts FROM [MyTable] GROUP BY [SupposedlyUnique] HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) 
SELECT SUM(Counts) FROM MySubquery
```

What I want to do is combine these two, so I can run a single query to return a percent-population of rows that are part of a duplicate group on a supposedly unique field.

However, popping query #2 into the conditional subquery in query #1 doesn't work:

```
SELECT
CONVERT(Decimal(5,2), CONVERT(Decimal(5,4), CONVERT(Float, (
WITH MySubquery AS (
SELECT COUNT([SupposedlyUnique]) AS Counts FROM [MyTable] GROUP BY [SupposedlyUnique] HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) 
SELECT SUM(Counts) FROM MySubquery
))/(
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [MyTable] --Numerator doesn't need to be converted
))*100)
```

"Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
;WITH MySubquery AS (
SELECT COUNT([SupposedlyUnique]) AS Counts FROM [MyTable] GROUP BY [SupposedlyUnique] HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) 
SELECT
CONVERT(Decimal(5,2), CONVERT(Decimal(5,4), CONVERT(Float, ( (SELECT SUM(Counts) FROM MySubquery))/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [MyTable]))*100)
```

Comment: This works after removing a left-parentheses just before `( (SELECT SUM(Counts)...` - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use CTE as sub-query, move CTE out of the query and use below instead

```
WITH MySubquery AS (
        SELECT COUNT([SupposedlyUnique]) AS Counts
        FROM [MyTable]
        GROUP BY [SupposedlyUnique]
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(5, 2), 
            CONVERT(DECIMAL(5, 4), 
                CONVERT(FLOAT, (SELECT SUM(Counts) FROM MySubquery) / 
                                (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [MyTable])
                )
            * 100))
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Really helpful to learn about CTE as well!

Answer (score 1):

Another example - output percentage for every duplicate group (with Total ) :

```
select UniqID = case 
                   when GROUPING_id([SupposedUnique]) = 1 then 'Total' 
                   else [SupposedUnique] end,   
       Percentage = CONVERT(Decimal(5,2),sum(cnt))
from (
      select distinct [SupposedUnique]
             ,cnt =  CONVERT(Float, 
                     COUNT(*) over ( partition by [SupposedUnique]))
                    /(COUNT(*) over ())*100
             ,cnt1 = COUNT(*) over ( partition by [SupposedUnique])  
      from [MyTable]) result
where result.cnt1 > 1
group by cube([SupposedUnique])
```